# Include all files of a type *.algspec into project in project folder with cmake

Tags: opencv, cmake

I am generating visual studio solution files for our project with cmake.

stucture is

```
/CmakeLists.txt
/include/
/src/
/file1.algspec
/file2.algspec
/file3.algspec
```

I included my current cmakelists file below. (notice that it is a opencv module so if there is anything in opencvs cmake stuff that helps, that is fine to use.

I want it to include all files of type algspec in the folder structure listed above into one project folder like opencv is doing for include and src files. The folder name could be "specs"

```
set(the_description "Ascend OpenCV Features")

ocv_define_module(ascend_features opencv_highgui opencv_features2d)


set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES "System;System.Core")
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/clr /EHa")
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX "d")

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /AI\"C:\\dev\\ascendprojects\\Ascend Azure Pipeline\\Ascend.Algorithms\\Ascend.Algorithms.Interface\\bin\\x64\\Release\" ")

if(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG MATCHES "/RTC1")
   string(REPLACE "/RTC1" " " CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
endif()

if(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS MATCHES "/EHsc")
   string(REPLACE "/EHsc" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif()




message(STATUS ${the_module})
```

if possible, its also okay to update my cmakeslist to make the dll that it import to a setting that can be set in cmake gui. else it will be a new question later.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the solution.

Didnt fin a way to get them into a folder

```
set(the_description "Ascend OpenCV Features")


macro(ocv_get_module_external_sources)
    file(GLOB SPECS "*.algspec")
    set(__filesvar "OPENCV_MODULE_${the_module}_HEADERS")
    list(APPEND ${__filesvar} ${SPECS} )    
endmacro()

ocv_define_module(ascend_features opencv_highgui opencv_features2d opencv_nonfree)


set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES VS_DOTNET_REFERENCES "System;System.Core")
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/clr /EHa")
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX "d")

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /AI\"C:\\dev\\ascendprojects\\Ascend Azure Pipeline\\Ascend.Algorithms\\Ascend.Algorithms.Interface\\bin\\x64\\Release\" ")

if(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG MATCHES "/RTC1")
   string(REPLACE "/RTC1" " " CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
endif()

if(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS MATCHES "/EHsc")
   string(REPLACE "/EHsc" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif()


message(STATUS ${the_module})
```